# Visual Studio Web test cookie management

Tags: web-testing

I have read in other posts that Visual Studio Web Test automatically handles cookies. I am using Fiddler to examine traffic when I use me AUT (application under test) in order to try and replicate calls in Web Test. I see cookies in the requests in Fiddler that I am not seeing in Web Test. Do I have to extract them and add them to subsequent requests? Is there some kind of automagical please handle cookies for me setting somewhere? Thanks for helping the noon. I cannot find anything on google.

Answer (score 1):

No. There should be no need for you to handle the cookies yourself.

For me, Visual Studio has always handled the cookies without my doing anything special with, or for, cookies. I have not found any switches to enable or disable cookie handling.

There are some cookie related fields in the request and response. They can be read and, for requests, modified for a website that does some non-standard cookie mixtures.

Comment: the Ref Guide says: "The cookie collection that Visual Studio sends with requests is dynamically built based on the cookies sent back from the server. There is a method that allows you to add a new cookie to the collection, but there is no exposed way to delete an existing cookie.
Further, the collection itself is marked as read-only, so if you create a new cookie collection using System.Net and then assign it to the request's cookie collection, the request will fail to execute"  any workarounds out there?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Are you asking a question? If so then please post it as a new question. Your comment here is likely to be read by only a few people.

Comment: no, it was ment as additional information additional to your answer